# CSS and page resizing

Tags: html, css

I`m setting up a simple page with a top section and
the portion below split into vertical sections.

The left section contains a site menu, the right section
holds verbiage and the middle is a space between left and
right (not needed?).

My issues:

1. When the page is resized horizontally , the right
   section moves over the left totally obscuring the site menu.
2. Text in the right section wraps over into the left below
   the site menu. I'd like the text in the right section to stay in the
   right section.

[image: menu being obscured]

```
.top {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}


.ileft {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
}

.imiddle {
    width: 5%;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
}

.iright {
   width: 80%;
   float: left
   margin-left: 30px;
   background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: There are newer CSS tools like [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) or [`grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) that don't require the use of `float`. You might be looking for the [holy grail](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/) layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please do as others said and use either `flex` or `grid` to create this layout.**

But if you want to go with this setup for some reason, the problem with your code is that you have a missing `;` after your `float` property in the `.iright` selector and you need to set your width to `calc(80% - 30px)` so it considers the `margin-left` property (or just remove the `margin-left`).

```css
/* Added so you can see the output better */
div {
  height: 40px;
}

.top {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.ileft {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}

.imiddle {
    width: 5%;
    float: left;
    background-color: purple;
}

.iright {
   width: calc(80% - 30px);
   float: left;
   padding: left;
   margin-left: 30px;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">Top</div>
<div class="ileft">Left</div>
<div class="imiddle">M</div>
<div class="iright">Right</div>
```

**Please do as others said and use either `flex` or `grid` to create this layout.**

Comment: I'll have to research flex/grid. Obviously, I don't even know css. Your css example did everything except stopping a resize from covering the menu. I've added a graphic to my question taken after I applied your edit and after a resize.

Comment: I'm now using Flex.  What a great tool!  I wish I could award the answer to everyone who mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

-You can use "media queries" to re-adjust your content according to the size of the screen, in whichever way you want including font-size, for example: when it resizes itself to a smaller size using the media queries, the text won't wrap.

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

-And you should also check alternative layout methods other than float such as:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. You may want to use a more flexible way to layout the page (flex, grids, ...)

Oh, and you are welcome about those delightful colors.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
}

.iLikeFlex {
 display: flex
}

header {
  background-color: MediumSlateBlue;
  height: 50px;
}

.ileft {
  /* Fixed width - 150px */
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  background-color: DeepPink;
}

.imiddle {
  /* Fills all remaining space */
  flex: 1;
  /* But you still can limit its min or max size*/
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: PeachPuff;
}

.iright {
  /* Fixed width - 200px */
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<header></header>

<div class="iLikeFlex">
  <div class="iright"></div>
  <div class="imiddle"></div>
  <div class="ileft"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you got to know about these color names? A good reference sheet you're using or you just knew it by heart?

Comment: Well, grab a coffee because there is a [lot of em](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/color-names/). I know a few, but it's not really useful.

Answer (score 1):

```html
/* Column container */
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox; 
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


/* left column */
.side {
  -ms-flex: 20%; 
  flex: 20%;
  background-color:green;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Main column */
.main {
  -ms-flex: 80%; 
  flex: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  float: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Comment: You might as well want to use flex and create columns instead. No space in between is needed.